# How accurate to the original story is the Witcher Netflix series?

Tags: adaptation-comparison, the-witcher

So, I personally have not read the books, or played the games. I was aware of the series and the setting, but that's about it.

After watching the series through several times now however, there were some things that seemed too far out of place

> Like the fight scene between Vilgefortz and Cahir, followed by the shit where he killed the injured mage. The fight was inconsistent (a powerful and experienced mage throwing a 1v1 fight against a regular* knight) and killing the injured mage was just completely out of context (the only reason I knew he was a mage was because he recognised Vilgefortz, and the fallen Niflgaard soldiers panned out before him).

[This Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/netflixwitcher/comments/edg4ux/my_take_on_vilgefortz_in_season_1_spoilers/?utm_source=amp&utm_medium=&utm_content=post_body) suggests that

> Vilgefortz purposefully threw the fight to trick the other mages - he was acting as a turncoat, which from the original series he ends up being the bad guy.

However the inconsistent part is that (according to the thread)

> Vilgefortz is meant to be the "hero of Sodden"; but Yennefer (at this point) seems to have taken that mantle.

So how accurate to the original story is the Netflix series? Is it an adaptation that simply requires a bit of reworking to fit the "tv series format", or is it more like GoT, where they altered the story completely to avoid spoilers?

<sup>*Admittedly Cahir is not meant to be just a "regular" knight - I simply mean that he has no magical abilities of his own.</sup>

Comment: Unless you're looking for a list of instances, I'd say it's totally accurate in some parts, totally inaccurate in others, and somewhat accurate everywhere else.

Comment: It seems to me, It is a bit like with GoT later seasons, just in the start this time - they fitted short stories to novels filling the gaps as they saw fit and giving Yen and Ciri PoV when they didn't have them. Some of this stuff is gonna go into next season, but it should clear up as they go on with adapting novels. That being said this is all more or less opinion based, while asking about Sodden is OK, asking about "general accuracy" is not.

Answer (score 3):

The Battle of Sodden Hill is not described in detail in any book - we just know that 22 mages have fought on the side of the Northern Kingdoms and 14 (officially, 13 in practice since Marigold has survived) of them have died. We know for sure that what the show presented was only the small (but the most famous) part of the battle - a bit like the real-life [Thermopylae battle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Thermopylae), mostly remembered by the 300 Spartans, not by the ~6000 other Greeks. In fact, the army of the North was quite numerous and apparently (as mentioned in the "Blood of the Elves") it became popular to brag that "you were fighting at Sodden".

Now regarding Vilgeforz - again we know little about him: he was raised as among druids, spent his youth as a mercenary and since birth, he had magical skills (which suggest that one or both of his parents were mages).

Now, the OP question asks about two things - his motivation and skills:

1. Vilgeforz has only one motivation: his own power. He is already a very talented (although young) wizard, but he craves political power, hence he made (at least twice) a deal with the Emperor Emhyr:

> Once, when he helped in his rise to power and later, during the coup d'etat on the Thanedd island that destroyed trust in mages.

However, in the end, he is working only for himself and he wants to get Ciri for his own goals.

During the Battle of Sodden Hill, in the book he was the de-facto leader of the mages and he engineered the peace, gaining the mantle of a hero - while this seems to be an inconsistency, it is very easy to explain: after the battle most of the wizards are dead, Yennefer (who was politically inconvenient to the Council) is nowhere to be seen, but here comes the young and brave Vilgeforz, so let's now start saying that he was in charge all along!

2. His swordsmanship: yes, in the book Vilgeforz kicks Geralt's ass badly - but that takes place quite a while after the Battle of Sodden. We know, that from his career as a mercenary he would be a decent swordsman, but that career was in the past - since he became a mage he probably had little time and motivation to properly practice his fighting skills, so instead on the rare chance of melee combat, he can rely on his old skills spiced up with just a little bit of magic. But then he meets Cahir who humiliates him, which would give him motivation to improve his skills - I personally really doubt that he has thrown this fight since you can see how angry he is afterwards redirecting later his anger on a wounded comrade.

So in total, I wouldn't say that the series is much different (in this case) from the books - rather it feels the gaps that the books have omitted.

Comment: We know a bit more about this battle - and it's quite inconsistent with series - Yennefer was blinded by Fringilla, and Triss got her hair completely burnt. While V. wasn't shown in this time, he already had this maelstrom-thingy of his since he used this to cover up disappearance of Duny.

Comment: Vilgeforz in the books uses some manner of powerful spell in the books, the exact nature is vague, but it seems it allows him to predict the combat moves Geralt makes, kind of like slowing time for himself or some such. His natural swordsmanship skill was probably nothing special.

Answer (score -2):

From everything I've heard about the background of the show, is that the show is supposed to be a prequel to the books, and the books are a prequel to the games.

I'm currently listening to the books on Audible, and a lot of the first episode is in The Last Wish which is basically a prequel book set before the first published book. A few details are off but the stories stay true (So far no Jaskier in the books) and the book is very time jumpy and flash backy.

Comment: Jaskier is called "Dandelion" in the English books, "Jaskier" is the original Polish name. "The Last Wish" and "Sword of Destiny"  have been published before the bigger series.